# If Cell.Value > (Greater Than) function not working to color cells

Tags: excel, vba

The code that Im currently using.

```
Dim iRowCq As Range
Set iRowCq = Range("B2:DJ26")

For Each Cell In iRowCq

    If Cell.Value > "0.3" or cell.value > 0.3 Then
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If

Next
```

I want to color cells that are greater than 0.3 green. Yet while 99% of the cells work, there are sometimes cells that are greater than 0.3 and are not colored. Ive even tried rounding the data to two decimal points before which did not work. Could someone please help?

[Screen shot of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTTel.png)

Comment: I think you need to look at what value is actually stored in the cells that aren't going green. I'm particularly looking at the value being something like `0.2999`, but it displays as `0.3`.

Comment: Is there conditional formatting that is overriding the rogue cells?

Comment: What is the value that is shown in the 'Formula Bar' for the cells that are misbehaving?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combine string and numerical comparisons like that for *greater than/less than* comparisons. A string might not be greater than `"0.3"` as a string but it will always be sorted higher than `0.3` as a number.` A combination string and numerical comparison might work on a strictly *equals to* basis.

Take the numerical value of either a string or a mixed number and use that for coparison.

```
Dim iRowCq As Range Set iRowCq = Range("B2:DJ26")

For Each Cell In iRowCq

    If val(Cell.Value) > 0.3 Then
         Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If

Next
```

Comment: I would have thought that the OP's code would have worked if the cell contains a numeric value. Did you test the OP's code before offering an alternative?

Comment: If the op had `"0.3"` in a cell, that is always alphabetically larger than `0.3` as a number. You're thinking that the cell value changes from text to a number depending on what it is compared to; that's not the case. Either the cell value is text or a number anf if it is text the latter pat of the op's two-fold comparison will always be true.

Comment: This is just the most recent version of the code as I was out of ideas. I've tried numerically and as a string individually, neither worked. The cell values that are not being colored are small numbers with many decimals (ex. 0.6512442834805).

Comment: "You're thinking that the cell value changes from text to a number" - No, I'm not. I'm thinking that the OP has numbers throughout all of their cells but they have panicked and added the string comparison to try and debug

Comment: Well, I guess that is why a [mcve] is recommended as part of the original question. It tends to avoid Whack-a-Mole games in the response area as well as extended comment exchanges..

Comment: And exactly correct Enigmativity, started as just numerical and it didnt work, adding the string comparizon was just a way to see if it would work.... it didn't.

Comment: I used the example code given just to be sure. The cell value 0.621583957861 is still not being colored as green, even though it is greater than 0.3

Answer (score 1):

Why are you re-inventing conditional formatting? It can be done in a very simple way, without needing VBA:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- It s better practise to specify the worksheet

        Set rng = .Range("B2:DJ26") '<- This range does not cover your whole spreadsheet. As i can see from the image the last column IS NOT "D" BUT "S" and the last row IS NOT 26 BUT 25. Setting range to *.Range("B2:SJ25")* we cover your range.

        For Each cell In rng

            If CDec(cell.Value) > 0.3 Then '<- Convert the cell value into decimal in order to compare with decimal
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```